# 1920's terms for parents/children

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, history

What would young children (aged around 5-ish) have called their parents circa 1920's England? Were there specific terms of endearment, or would it just be "mother" and "father"? I'm particularly thinking of the upper classes, but all answers are appreciated.

As a side-question, would there have been informal terms of endearment for children, or would their parents have always called them by their first names?

Answer (score 5):

["Mummy" and "Daddy" seem extremely common in books from the period](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1920%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1929&tbm=bks&q=mummy+daddy&oq=mummy+daddy&gs_l=serp.3...8342.9226.0.9463.6.6.0.0.0.0.157.362.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.56.serp..5.1.44.BDDXzegMMvk), just as they are in the UK today. (*Mummy* as a word for *mother* is all but unknown in American English, which prefers *mommy*, so it's probably safe to assume that most of the results from that search are British.)

Comment: 'Mummy' and 'Daddy' were used when we were very small, and it was a little milestone when we moved to 'Mum' and 'Dad' at what - 7 years old or thereabouts?  This was also my mum's experience (b1922, Salford)

Answer (score 2):

Mam and dad was common, as was mum and dad. This according to mom, born in '26 in Grimsby.

Comment: _Mam_? Or did you mean _mom_?

Comment: yes, I mean mam. My cousin still calls her mom 'mam'.

Comment: Okay, I see. I thought it's a typo. +1

Comment: @NVZ *Mam* is used in some regions of Britain, mainly in the Midlands, but also in various places north of the Trent.

Comment: @Phil - and do/did you call your mum 'mom'?

Comment: Yes, I was born in the US.